# Re-setting the delay after the timer has started to fire

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, event-handling

In my program i have a timer that fires event every 100th of a second.The timer starts as soon as my program starts.*(The call to start the timer is from the constructor)*

**Is there any way to reset the the `delay` of firing events by the timer once it has started?**

My timer starts in the following fashion :

`new Timer( 100 , taskPerformer).start();`

### why i am trying to achieve this:

As soon as the program starts `Bouncing ball animation` starts.I have a `JSlider` that goes from `0` to `1000` miliseconds on it's scale.Initially the delay is set to `100th milisecond`.
I should be able to reset the delay using `JSlider`. I am done with my program except `resetting the delay`.

### What is the method?

Comment: what prevented you from reading the api doc?

Comment: @ kleopatra I knew the answer before it was posted. I read api doc. It was a mistake that **at first** i didn't turn to Doc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also change the timer's delay afterwards using method [`Timer.setDelay(...);`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html#setDelay%28int%29).